# How to show consequence in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I wrote

> In particular, we employ textual delimiters and semantic cues within the content to identify data regions **and build the content structure.**

or

> In particular, we employ textual delimiters and semantic cues within the content to identify data regions **, thus building the content structure.**

***building the content structure*** is a consequence of the previous clause. 
Actually, we identify data regions, the structure of these regions makes the content structure.

the cause is not so direct that I can use "thus" or "to", yet not so shallow that I use "and".

how can I show that with some structure or words?

---

To get the context, the whole abstract so far is

> In this paper, we present an approach and a system, called ABDES, for constructing web wrappers to extract data records from a web page. In our approach, we simulate the way a human user scans a web page for specific data. In particular, we rely on textual delimiters and identifiable constants or patterns within the page content to recognize data regions. Based on the extracted data, the content structure is built and mapped onto a hierarchical XML structure as output. The system provides robust and maintainable wrappers that are not tailored to the HTML structure of the page. As a result, they can be adapted to gather and integrate information from various websites. We offer a polynomial-time algorithm to implement the proposed technique.

Comment: Grammatically/syntactically, ***and*** and ***thus*** are both fine (or you could use ***to***). It's a stylistic choice, depending on whether you want to emphasize the *sequence*, the *consequence*, or the *purpose*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers the cause is not so direct that I can use "thus" or "to", yet not so shallow that I use "and"

Comment: It is not clear how the mere identification of a data region (where it starts, where it ends) results in the building of its *structure*.  The "thus" seems unwarranted.

Comment: @TRomano: It seems credible to me. It's a software context, so I assume a "content structure" is a special (hierarchically?) organised set of "data regions". As you identify each, you store it appropriately in that (originally empty) set/structure, thus "building" (populating, manifesting) the structure (of a web page, for example).

Comment: @FumbleFingers yes I mean that, data regions can be nested and hierarchically organized, and by content structure I mean discovering that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I may say *and their underlying structure*

Comment: So, content-regions contain data-regions whose boundaries are identified by textual delimiters and/or semantic cues?

Comment: This is descending into fine details of exactly *what* is being said, and how best to express it. For all I know, the actual intended meaning might be best conveyed by ***allowing us to** build the content structure*. But it's as much a matter of learning how to *think* as it is about learning how to use English.

Comment: I like to learn new patterns, **allowing us to build** was a useful pattern, thank you

Comment: @TRomano yes, I put the whole abstract in the question so you can get an idea of the article

Answer (score 1):

The use of "***and***" (the first example) suggests that your employing (of textual delimiters and semantic cues) is used for **both** the process of *identifying* and the process of *building*, but nothing points to the fact that *building* takes place after *identifying* or that they are in some way dependent.

The use of "***thus***" (the second example) implies the strong dependence (temporal and causal) between the act of *employing* and the act of *building* (note the difference - in the first example it was *identifying* and *building*).  If that is what you want, use "thus".  If you want to show the dependency between *building* and *identifying data regions*, the latter is buried too much to stand out, the first clause needs to be rewritten somewhat.  But I somehow doubt that that is what you want.

There is nothing unprofessional in using "***and***", it just gives a different meaning to the statement.

---

Taking the latest edits in the question into consideration, I'd rewrite the sentence as

> In particular, we employ textual delimiters and semantic cues within the content, ***from which*** we identify data regions ***and then*** build the content structure ***from them***.

A bit more verbose than the original, yet no ambiguity...

Comment: As you said *thus* is strong for my purpose, you didn't say the solution.

Comment: You alone know what you're trying to say.  It's up to you to find *the solution*.  You say that "building the content structure*" is a consequence. Of what **exactly**?  Of employing or identifying?

Comment: we identify data regions, the structure of these regions makes the content structure

Comment: I recommend putting this addition in your question so a better answer could be provided.